# Get data out from callback inside query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, react-native, parse-server

I am trying to get data out from query inside the query. I tried everything without success.

```
getvideos() {
            var sectionHolder = [];
            var ids = [];
            var titles = [];
            var videos = [];
            var challengeCl = Parse.Object.extend("Challenges");
            var query = new Parse.Query(challengeCl);

                query.find().then((data) => {

                    for(var key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {
                        var object = data[key];
                        var videoid = object.id;
                        var title =  object.get('title');
                        ids.push(videoid)
                        titles.push(title)
                            var video = Parse.Object.extend('Videos');
                            var queryv = new Parse.Query(video);
                                queryv.equalTo('challengeid', videoid);
                                queryv.find().then( 
                                    (video) => { 
                                        videos.push(video); //i want to get this data out from this scope
                                });

                                sectionHolder.push({title: title, data: videos}); // <---- i want to put videos data in data 
                    } 
                    console.log(sectionHolder);
                    this.setState({listData: sectionHolder});
                });
}
```

I read parse documentation but there is nothing related to this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "trying to get data out from the query inside the query"... get it out how? A copy? As the `this.state` variable you have in your function? Are you simply not seeing the data come out when you step through? Also, why are all of your `find()` functions empty? This requires you give it a callback with criteria to "search" for in your object. Wouldn't `find()` return nothing since the query is empty.

Comment: i can not get data from variable videos. i already try find({ (data) => videos.push(data) }); but when i tried to access the variable out of the scope i see an empty array